# document.getElementByClassName returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, nodes, nodelist

I am gettings `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'document.getElementByClassName("selceted")')` when trying to get the class name or ID of the div. and I cannot figure out why. The array/nodelist is NOT empty, it has ALL the data in from every `timeline-item` post, and only 1 has the class of `selected` so how do I get only that element?

Here is my code so far:

```
if($.inArray(postdate, post_image_dates)){
    var posts = $(".timeline-item");
    posts.removeClass("selected");
    var matchedPost = posts.filter("[data-date='" + postdate + "']");

    if(matchedPost.length > 0){
        matchedPost.addClass("selected");

        var more_post_content = document.createElement('div');
        more_post_content.id = 'more_post_content';

        var ul = document.createElement('ul');
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = '<a href="#"><img src="' + postdata + '"/></a>';

        ul.appendChild(li);
        more_post_content.appendChild(ul);
        var elementArray;

        elementArray = [].slice.call(matchedPost, 0);
        console.log(elementArray);
        if($.inArray('selected', elementArray)){
            var select = document.getElementByClassName("selceted");
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no function `getElementByClassName`. It's getElement**s**. And as the name says, it does not return a single element.

Comment: Note that `if($.inArray('selected', elementArray))` should be `if($.inArray('selected', elementArray) > -1)`. Your condition fails if the `elementArray` is the first element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `getElementByClassName` to `getElementsByClassName` also the class name that you are used is incorrect.

```
if($.inArray('selected', elementArray)){
   var select = document.getElementsByClassName("selected");
   //..............................^................^.........
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `selceted` to `selected`

and `getElementByClassName` to `getElementsByClassName`, final `select` variable should be:

```
if($.inArray('selected', elementArray)){
    var select = document.getElementsByClassName("selected");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just some spelling mistakes here

```
document.getElementByClassName("selceted");
```

change to

```
document.getElementsByClassName("selected");
```

**Syntax**

```
elements = document.getElementsByClassName(names); // or:
elements = rootElement.getElementsByClassName(names);
```

**Example**

Get all elements that have a class of `'test'`

```
document.getElementsByClassName('test');
```